# Spring Boot JAR Distribution

Tags: spring-boot

I have developed my first Spring Boot application and packaged a JAR using Maven.
When I launch it on my machine, no issues.
When a different client launches it they will get an error if they don't have the same version of Java as I developed it in (Java 8).
I had made the assumption that everything would be packaged into a self contained JAR with everything it needs to run (like when I create native packaging with JavaFX).
Am I missing something?  What are the best practices for distribution a Spring Boot JAR?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always try to keep same environment of your local and server configuration.

Comment: And another thing, if any kind of error occurs please share the log file or error details so that everyone can understand what was the actual cause?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  That is what I figured.  All my users have Java 7 on their machines, so I'll just retool it for that.